# Ajustar automaticamente el height de un div hijo al height del div padre

Tags: html, css, less

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

less

```
.content-card {
            width: 32rem;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(154,154,154,.78);
            background: #fff;

            .content-img {

                .img-a {
                    width: 320px;
                    height: 150px;
                }
            }

            .content-texte {
                padding: 3px 20px;
                text-align: center;

                .margen-derecho {
                    margin-right: 10px;
                }

                .sub {
                    margin-top: 10px;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;

                    .card-title {
                        font-size: 12px;
                        font-family: @MuseoSans_7;
                        color: @color-purple;
                        text-transform: uppercase;
                    }
                }





                .caracteristicas {
                    padding: 0 10px;

                    .lbl-carec {
                        margin: 10px 0;
                        font-family: @MuseoSans_7;
                        color: #000;
                        font-size: 22px;
                    }
                }

                .precio {
                    margin: 10px 0;

                    span {
                        display: block;
                    }

                    .texte {
                        font-family: @MuseoSans_3;
                        font-size: 12px;
                        color: @color-gray-winp;
                    }

                    .price {
                        font-family: @MuseoSans_9;
                        color: @color-purple;
                        font-size: 24px;
                    }
                }

                .detalles {
                    margin: 10px 0;

                    a {
                        font-family: @MuseoSans_7;
                        font-size: 17px;
                        color: @color-green;
                    }
                }
            }


            .card-footer {
                .btn-agregar {
                    background: @color-green;
                    width: 100%;
                    border-radius: 0;
                    border: 0;
                    text-transform: none;
                    text-align: center !important;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    padding: 6px 12px;
                    font-family: MuseoSans_9;
                    font-size: 19px;
                    color: #fff;
                    letter-spacing: 1px;
                }
            }
        }
```

html

```
<div class="card-hotel">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 box-image">
                            <img class="card-img-top img-a" src="https://cdn.mexicodestinos.com/hoteles/hotel-moon-palace-cancun-slide-princ-min.jpg" alt="hotel bla bla">

                            <div class="destinoo">
                                <span> Playa suites Acapulco </span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="descuento_cora">
                                <span class="kokoro">
                                    <i id="kokoro" class="fh-icon fh-icon-people-icon tam"></i>
                                </span>

                                <span class="desc">
                                    40% DE DTO
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-7 information">
                            <div class="title-card-hotel">
                               <span class="nombre">Hotel playa suites Acapulco ¡Todo Incluido!</span>
<%--                                <div class="table-generic">
                                    <div class="tb-col-card space-obj"></div>
                                    <div class="tb-col-card"></div>
                                    <div class="tb-col-card categorias space-obj"></div>
                                </div>--%>

                                <div class="datos-hotel">
                                    <span><i class="inser-line"><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-estrella-icon format_star"></i><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-estrella-icon format_star"></i><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-estrella-icon format_star"></i><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-estrella-icon format_star"></i></i></span>
                                    <span class="ciudad">Puerto Vallarta</span>
                                    <span class="tag-cate">Familiar</span> <span class="tag-cate">Familiar</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="servicios">
                                <ul class="list-servicios">
                                    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> 2 adultos</li>
                                    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> 2 niños</li>
                                    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> Habitación estandar</li>
                                    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> Plan alimenticio</li>
                                    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> Plan alimenticio</li>
                                    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> Plan alimenticio</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="prices">
                                <div class="title"><span>PRECIO</span></div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 desc">
                                        <span class="money">1,999</span>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-md-6  prec">
                                        <div class="table-generic">
                                            <div class="tb-col price-final">3,639</div>
                                            <div class="tb-col tb-top moneda-final">mxn</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cont-button">
                                        <button class="btn btn-cambiar">CAMBIAR</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="desc-nota">
                                <span class="msg-desc">AL ELEGIR ESTE HOTEL AHORRARAS 1,000 MXN</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

El div box-imagen, no se adapta al tamaño del div padre, que es el card-hotel, de que forma puedo solucionarlo?

he intentado poniendo esto a la clase box-text

```
background: url(https://cdn.mexicodestinos.com/hoteles/hotel-moon-palace-cancun-slide-princ-min.jpg) no-repeat fixed center;
                background-size: cover;
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                bottom:0;
```

pero ahora el div de information se pone encima de box-text

Comment: Estás utilizando algun framework? bootstrap o algo asi?

Comment: bootstrap Y Less

Comment: Qué versión de Bootstrap? la versión 4 usa flexbox y debería ser fácil hacer lo que pides con Flexbox `align-items: stretch`  o `height: 100%`

Comment: sabes si en la version 3 existe?

Comment: Bootstrap 3 no usa flexbox. Con el codigo que muestras podrias usar algo como ```.box-image {
 overflow: hidden;
 img {
  height: 100%;
 }
}```

Comment: Pero te recomiendo usar bootstrap 4 y aprender flexbox, van a facilitar mucho tu trabajo.

Comment: @Turqueso voy a intentar tu solución

Comment: porque por el momento sólo voy a usar bootstrap 3

Answer (score 1):

La solución de la posición absoluta debe funcionar, el problema es que al convertir `.box-image` a posición absoluta, se "desordena" el resto del grid... si agregas otro elemento `.col-md-5` en ese lugar, debería mantenerse la integridad del resto del layout.

Quizá yo lo hubiese solucionado de esta manera:

```
/* En el media query del breakpoint md en adelante */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    .card-img-top {
        width: 320px;
        height: auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: auto;
        object-fit: cover;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .descuento_cora, .destinoo {z-index: 2} /* aqui asumo que tienen posicion absoluta */
}
```